# Getting UV maps from UDK?

Tags: xna, textures, maps, udk, uv-mapping

I have created a map using UDK and I am exporting it as a .fbx for use within an XNA project.

My question is, can I generate a UV map for texturing the map or is there an easier way to texture a map made within UDK to be used in an XNA project?

Thanks.

Comment: when you say you exported a map, do you mean a piece of geometry (for example the terrain of a level) ?

or did you make an entire level with assets etc.. within UDK and export the entire thing?

Comment: I created the map using the BSP brushes then exported it all as a .fbx

Comment: if you were keeping it in UDK Vertex Blending would be  an option http://udn.epicgames.com/Two/VertexBlendingTutorial.html

im not sure if this is possible in XNA or if you would have to make it custom, the other option is to uv map the bsp in your desired modelling package and texture as you would a normal asset but with a larger map - even better would be to break this asset down into multiple assets so you dont have to use huge textures - just lots of small ones

Comment: So are you saying to texture it within UDK then try and export the textures built into the model?

Comment: sadly i dont think you can do that unless you build the game in udk - you will either have to export and cut up the asset into small texture sizes - or implement your own vertex blending method in XNA

Comment: Is there a way for me to export my map from UDK into 3DS Max where I can then apply the textures?

Comment: yes if you managed to export the fbx - that should import into 3dsmax, you will then need to go through the process of uv mapping and applying textures in max

Comment: Hi I managed to get my map into 3DS Max and then UV wrap/map it. The textures all work but after this process some of my walls have moved and I cannot re-position them within 3DS Max. Do you know what is happening here?

Comment: I guess when you exported it from UDK it merged all the BSP into one object, so in Max right click on the mesh - convert to poly- then go to element mode and try moving the individual pieces - it may help to detach the parts as separate objects

Comment: I am fairly new to 3DS Max, could you explain to me how to separate the objects?

Comment: in element mod with the element you want selected (in red) click detach - a dialogue will popup make sure - as object is selected and click ok

Comment: When I use the element tool rather than selecting 1 wall it is selecting all of them that is touching it. Will I need to separate them all in UDK first?

Comment: ahhhh your bsp export is literally one mesh object, you can either select each poly of each wall in polygon mode then detach - or to be honest build it in max - its far better for creating your geometry than UDK

Comment: In UDK every wall is a new BSP but they are all intersecting so that there would be no gaps. Yeah it looks like I will have to, I was just trying not to have to do it in 3DS Max as I am very new to it and takes me a while to do things with me being new to it.

Comment: Never mind I did have it all as 1 BSP brush, I removed all of the individual walls so that there was 100% no gapes between them.